# Prediction interval for a given value not in dataset in SAS

Tags: statistics, sas, prediction

I used a proc reg to come up with my prediction intervals:

```
PROC REG data = steers;
    model y = x / cli;
    run;
```

Here's my output for the proc reg [image]

I need to construct a 95% interval for y = 300. How would I do that?

Comment: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/02/19/scoring-a-regression-model-in-sas.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Save model to data set to pass to PROC SCORE, call it modelParams.
2. Create data set to pass to PROC SCORE with data points required for prediction
3. Run PROC SCORE

Other options include:

- Using a CODE statement to generate data step code to process a data set from Step 2
- Adding in a fake data point to your original data, that is 300 but no y value so it gets a prediction
- PROC PLM instead of SCORE, same functionality mostly
- Manually save estimates to a data set and manually calculate the estimates
- Use a SCORE statement within a PROC, if available.

Most are outlined [here with examples](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/02/19/scoring-a-regression-model-in-sas.html).

Step 1

```
PROC REG data = steers outest=modelParams;
    model y = x / cli;
    run;
```

Step 2

```
data newValues;
input x;
cards;
300
;;;;
```

Step 3

```
proc score data=newValues score=modelParamstype=parms predict out=Pred;
   var x;
run;
```